# DyanamoDB SCAN with nested attribute

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

Can I scan DynamoDB by 'order.shortCode', in the given example.  The console is indicating I can't with dot notation, and I can't find any documentation on it.

```
{    
  "key2": "cj11b1ygp0000jcgubpe5mso3",
  "order": {
    "amount": 74.22,
    "dateCreated": "2017-04-02T19:15:33-04:00",
    "orderNumber": "cj11b1ygp0000jcgubpe5mso3",
    "shortCode": "SJLLDE"
  },
  "skey2": "SJLLDE"
}
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

To scan by a nested attribute, you should use `ExpressionAttributeNames` parameter to pass each path component (i.e. order and shortCode) separately into `FilterExpression` like shown below:

```
var params = {
    TableName: 'YOUR_TABLE_NAME',
    FilterExpression: "#order.#shortCode = :shortCodeValue",
    ExpressionAttributeNames: {
        '#order': 'order',
        "#shortCode": "shortCode"
    },
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
        ':shortCodeValue': 'SJLLDE'
    }
};

dynamodbDoc.scan(params, function(err, data) {
});
```

Here is a link to documentation explaining this:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.ExpressionAttributeNames.html#Expressions.ExpressionAttributeNames.NestedAttributes