# DynamoDB in Node.js SDK - Scan and filter without specific array index

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries, aws-sdk-nodejs

I'm writing a simple scan operation in an AWS lambda for a DynamoDB table.

Each element of the table has properties `city` (string) and `lines` (array). Each *line* has a `line_id`.

Example record:

```
"city": "Sin",
"lines": [
    {
        "line_id": 111,
    },
    {
        "line_id": 4,
    }
]
```

I've been reading about using `FilterExpression` on a **nested attribute**, in this case `line_id`.

As I understand, in [this article](https://www.bmc.com/blogs/dynamodb-advanced-queries/) for example, under **Nested query** (sorry, no permalink), we can use something like this:

```
const { DynamoDBClient } = require('@aws-sdk/client-dynamodb');
const { ScanCommand } = require('@aws-sdk/lib-dynamodb');

const ddbClient = new DynamoDBClient({ region: 'region' });

const command = new ScanCommand({
    TableName: 'tableName',
    ProjectionExpression: 'city, lines',
    ExpressionAttributeNames: {
      '#line_id': 'line_id'
    },
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
      ':idd': 4
    },
    FilterExpression: 'lines.#line_id = :idd',
});

ddbClient.send(command);
```

in order to find records that contain at least one *line* with `line_id` equal to 4.

I'm receiving an empty result.

Is this approach plausible, or did I misunderstand the explanation?

Can this actually be done in DynamoDB, or do I have to do this in the code after I receive the entire scan result?

PS: found this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43175813) which also suggests something similar, but I just can't make it work.

Answer (score 1):

`lines` is a list, not an object. [You can use](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.Attributes.html#Expressions.Attributes.NestedAttributes) bracket indexing (`lines[0]`), but not dot-syntax (`lines.#line_id`) on a list.

Your scan will work if you refactor `lines` to be an object with `line_id` as the key and an list of `line_id` records as values.

```json
"lines": {
  111: [{ "line_id": 111}],
  4: [{ "line_id": 4}],
}
```

If that's not possible or worthwhile, you are stuck with a client-side or lambda-side transformation.